# I import another file by `import 'models.dart';`, it can't be compiled

Tags: import, dart

I have defined many dart files in my project, and they imported another file by `import`:

**controller.dart**

```
import 'models.dart';

// dart code
```

**app.dart**

```
import 'models.dart';
import 'controller.dart';

// dart code
```

**server.dart**

```
import "app.dart";

main() {
  // 
}
```

**more dart files**

But when I run `server.dart`, it reports error:

```
a library which is imported is missing a library directive: models.dart
```

What does that mean? Do I have to declare them all as libraries?

From the [language specification](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.eyqxfqjhe14t), it says:

```
It is a compile-time error if the compilation unit found at the 
specified URI is not a library declaration.
```

It seems we can only import a library, not normal files.

But if I define 2 simple files,

**a.dart**

```
import "b.dart";

main() {
   hello();
}
```

**b.dart**

```
hello() { print("hello!"); }
```

Then run a.dart:

```
dart a.dart
```

It can print `hello!`.

I get confused :(

Comment: yeah, I had the exact same problem when I started. long story short: library directives are required in every file you want to import, but sometimes the editor and VM fail to enforce this rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add library directive in each file that you want to import and all will be works fine.

In your case:

**models.dart**

```dart
library foo.models;    
// dart code
```

**controller.dart**

```dart
library foo.controller;    
import 'models.dart';    
// dart code
```

**app.dart**

```dart
library foo.app;
import 'models.dart';
import 'controller.dart';

// dart code
```

**server.dart**

```dart
 // If not planned to be imported then the name may be omitted
library foo.bin.server;
import "app.dart";

main() {
  // 
}
```

**Remember that each library that will be imported by another library requires unique name.**

The best way naming your libraries by prepending package name.

Eg.

The package name is `"worker"`.

**lib/worker.dart**

```dart
library worker.worker
```

**lib/work.dart**

```dart
library worker.work
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know we can use `foo.models` form.